# R doesn't recognize Latin7 characters

Tags: r, keyboard, latin

I have really strange problem. I am using Lithuanian keyboard, but R doesn't recognize letters such as į, š, č.

For example when I write:

```
žodis <- "žibutė"
```

in R console I see

```
þodis <- "þibutë".
```

I have `R` in several computers, all work fine except this one. Can you help me with this issue? Is any function to let R know that I'm using Lithuanian keyboard? My computer's operating system is Windows 10 and R version 3.3.2.

Comment: Look at the output if `sessionInfo()`, specifically the locales that are in use. Compare them across the computer that works and those that do not. I'm guessing that's the difference. Does typing work in other programs on this computer?

Comment: Yes, `sessionInfo()` differs. In this computer locale is `English United_States` and in other `Lithuanian Lithuania`.

Comment: I added `Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL","Lithuanian")`. Now everything works fine! Thank you, @MrFlick. ^^

Comment: Feel free to add that as an answer below to mark the question as answered.

Comment: Maybe someone knows way, that I shouldn't rewrite `Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL","Lithuanian")` everytime I start new R session? All other things work fine.:))

Comment: I think the value is inherited from the OS. So if you want to change the value of the OS, maybe try these steps: https://www.java.com/en/download/help/locale.xml (I know the page is for Java but the changes to the OS are not Java specific)

Comment: Applied and nothing... Problem still holds...

Comment: Did you restart R after changing the system setting?

Comment: Yes, computer restarted by itself

Comment: Ok, got it. When you want change locale into Lithuanian, you have to change date, time formats to Lithuanian, home locale to Lithuanian and, as you said, language for non-Unicode programs. Feel free to answer my question, i will vote it up. ^^ You helped me a lot!